# Error :"Maximum Update Depth Exceeded" Error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

**Sorry I am a newbie in React and working on useEffect function. Getting above error "Maximum Update Depth Exceeded".**

**Problem Statement:** I need to hide the icon based on visibility value. I have an object Location History which has multiple locations. I am binding locations on map based on coordinates and within circle showing all the locations. But I am not able to hide this within same circle radius.
Here is my code:

```
export const performLocationHistorySearch = () => async (dispatch) => {
  consolehelper("====================================");
  consolehelper("Executing History Search");
  
  let locationdata= store.getState().global.locationhistory;
  console.log("location history", locationdata);
  const center: Location = {
    lat: store.getState().global.searchLat,
    lng: store.getState().global.searchLng,
  };
  consolehelper(center);
  const radius = store.getState().global.searchRad;
  
  if (locationdata !== null) {
    console.log(locationdata);
    let _locations =locationdata.locations.map((el) => {
      const crowDistance = calculateCrowDistance(
        { lat1: parseFloat(el.latitude), lon1: parseFloat(el.longitude) },
        { lat2: center.lat, lon2: center.lng }
      );
      console.log(crowDistance);
        consolehelper("====================================");
        return {
          ...el,
          _isVisible_:
            radius >= crowDistance ,
          __distance: crowDistance,
        };
    });
    console.log(_locations.filter((el) => el._isVisible_));
    dispatch(globalSlice.actions.setlocationRecords({
      ...locationdata,
      locations:_locations
    }));
  }
};
```

Second piece of code calling locations, here it is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("====use effect location history====");
    if (locationhistory && searchRad && searchLat && searchLng) {
      dispatch(performLocationHistorySearch());
      console.log("====use effect location history====");
    }
  }, [
    dispatch,
      locationhistory,
    searchLat,
    searchLng,
    searchRad,
  ]);
```

While calling above function getting Error "maximum update depth exceeded". Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have an infinite loop of re-renders! That is why you are getting the above error.

Comment: Try removing dependencies from useEffect and try again. If error goes away then you can create another useEffect where you can conditionally set the state after dispatch.

Comment: No Luck, I tried with removal of dependency..